# PHPでUndefined variableエラー

Tags: php

PHPで下記の2つのエラーが出ます。

```
Warning: Undefined variable $row in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\news_table.php on line 88

Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\news_table.php on line 88
```

まず、1つ目は88行目の$rowが未定義変数と思っています。
それに伴い、2つ目のエラーが出ていると思っています。

従って、ソースコードの68行目で、isset($row)をして定義したつもりなのですが、エラーが消えません。
念のため、「検索」をクリックしましたが、それでもエラーは消えません。

エラー原因の究明にご協力いただければ幸いです。
ソースコードを添付します。

```
<?php
try{
    require_once("db_connect.php");
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$SERV;dbname=$DB;charset=$CHAR",$USER,$PASS);
}
catch(PDOException $e){echo "次がエラーの内容です。;" .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang=ja>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>News一覧</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Salon Yuri-rinの管理者ページ">
        <!--リセットcss-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css">
        <!--css-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/news_style.css">
        <!--レスポンシブ対応-->
        <meta name="viwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!--Googleフォント-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sawarabi+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shippori+Mincho:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>News一覧</h1>
        <table class="search_table">
        <form class="conditions" id="conditions" action="news_table.php" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="sdate">日付</label></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="sdate" id="sdate"></td>
                <td><label for="edate">～</label></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="edate" id="edate"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="title">タイトル</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="title" id="title"></td>
                <td><label>内容</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="content" id="title"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td><label>ステータス</label></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="status" id="status">
                        <option value="0">未公開</option>
                        <option value="1">公開</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" form="conditions"　name="search_button" value="検索" class="search_button">検索</button>
        <table class="tablehead">
            <tr>
                <th class="header">日付</th>
                <th class="header">タイトル</th>
                <th class="header">内容</th>
                <th class="header">公開ステータス</th>
                <th class="header2">
                    <form class="create" action="news_create.php">
                        <button type="submit" name="button" value="登録" class="button_a">登録</button>
                    </form>
                </th>
                <th class="header2"></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
            if(isset($_REQUEST['sdate']) && isset($_REQUEST['edate']) && isset($_REQUEST['title']) && isset($_REQUEST['content']) && isset($_REQUEST['status']) && isset($row) &&
                isset($_POST['search_button'])){
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql =
                ('select * from news where 
                    (pub_date >= ? and pub_date <= ?)
                    and title like ?
                    and content like ?
                    and status = ?');
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt ->execute(
                [htmlspecialchars(date_format(date_create($_REQUEST['sdate']),'Y-m-d'), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'),
                htmlspecialchars(date_format(date_create($_REQUEST['edate']),'Y-m-d'), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'),
                htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['title'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'),
                htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['content'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'),
                htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['status'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8'),]);
            $stmt->bindvalue(":title", "%" . $_REQUEST['title'] . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindvalue(":content", "%" . $_REQUEST['content'] . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}?>

            <?php foreach($row as $data):?>
            <form action="?" method="post" class = "newstblform">
                <div class = "table1">
                    <table class="newstable">
                        <tr>
                            <input type="hidden" name="seq" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['id'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id="seq">
                        <td class="dt">
                            <input type="text" name="pub_date" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['pub_date'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id="sei" readonly="readonly">
                        </td>
                        <td class="dt">
                            <input type="text" name="title" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['title'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id=mei readonly="readonly">
                        </td>
                        <td class="dt">
                            <input type="text" name="content" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['content'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id="sei_kana">
                        </td>
                        <td class="dt">
                            <input type="text" name="status" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($data['status'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')?>" id="sei_kana">
                        </td>
                        <td class="bt">
                            <input type="submit" name=button value="修正" formaction="news_update.php" class="button_a">
                        </td>
                        <td class="bt">
                            <input type="submit" name=button value="削除" formaction="news_delete_conf.php" class="button_a">
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本件、原因わかりました。
$STMTの指定に問題があり、SQLが実行できずに$rowがnullのままでした。
聞く前に自分で調査することが沢山ありました。
本件を確認いただいた方、調査いただいた方、お騒がせして申し訳ありません。
現在、別のエラーで悩んでいますが、そちらは別途質問させていただき、本件はクローズします。